# How to run multiple versions of sudo?

Tags: sudo, ld

My machine runs a patched version of `Sudo version 1.8.21p2` and I need to also have the unpatched version.

After getting the code from Github (the unpatched one), running `./configure`, and then `make` I stop short of `make install` because I want both version to co-exist.

Problem is:

```bsh
$ sudoup --version
sudoup: error while loading shared libraries: libsudo_util.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is also futile as `sudo`/`sudoup` just reset library paths.

How am I supposed to run this?

Comment: You can't use `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with setuid applications (otherwise it would be a huge security hole). You might be able to put one (and its libraries) under `/usr/local/{lib,etc,bin}` but you're probably safer trying to avoid having two distinct versions of the same security software

Comment: It's literally the same version, why is it not loading the original sudo's lib?

Comment: If it's the same version why do you need two separate instances?

Comment: one is patched by distributor, the other is not. https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4705-1

Comment: I can see why you want to apply to the security update, but unless it's for a pentest exercise I'm struggling to see why you'd want the unpatched edtition anywhere near your system

Comment: Yes, it's for pentest. Do you know how original `sudo` knows where to look for the lib? Even if I `mv sudoup sudo` it still can't find the lib.